# JavaFX: ListProperty and members notification

Tags: javafx, binding, javafx-8, listproperty

Consider the instances of a `Wrapper` class. The `Wrapper` class has the `ListProperty` of `ClassA` instances and the `ListProperty` of `ClassB` instancies.

```
public class Wrapper {
    private ListProperty<ClassA> aClasses;
    private ListProperty<ClassB> bClasses;

    public ListProperty<ClassA> aClassesProperty() { return aClasses; }
    public ListProperty<ClassB> bClassesProperty() { return bClasses; }

    // Methods…
}
```

The instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` need to know if they are included in some `Wrapper`. They may be included only in one `Wrapper` or not be included at all.

```
public class ClassA { // Similarly ClassB
    private Wrapper owner;
}
```

---

Some method of the `Wrapper` may remove member from one of ListProperties. I wonder if **JavaFX** has an automatic mechanism to **notify** a **removed member** of a **ListProperty**? Some binding mechanism between `ListProperty` of `Wrapper` and `owner` of `ClassA`/`ClassB`?

Answer (score 0):

You can go by this way if you are in `Wrapper class`:

```
aClasses.getValue().addListener(
                (ListChangeListener<ClassA>)event-> {
                    if (event.next()) {
                        if (event.wasAdded()) {

                        } else if (event.wasRemoved()) {

                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

Or change to : `owner.aClassesProperty().getValue().addListener(` if you are in `ClassA/B`

But for JavaFX there is : `FXCollections.observableList()` dedicated to Listeners on List, learn more https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm at half-page and here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html